# DDD (Domain-Driven Design) - Can Use Cases return Entity instances?

Tags: node.js, typescript, domain-driven-design, use-case, clean-architecture

### Can Use Cases return Entity instances?

I am asking, therefore, I see no other alternative.

I am rewriting an MVC application for `DDD` + `Clean Architecture`.

For example:

```js
function createUserUseCase (name: string): User {
    // Instantiate `User` Aggregate Root.
    const user = new User.create(name)

    // Store new user using the repository.
    UserRepository.store(user)

    return user
}
```

```js
class UserController {
    public async post (request: Request, response: Response): Promise<Response> {
        // Return `User` instance.
        return await response.json(createUserUseCase(request.body.name))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the biggest violation here is that you return the domain model. It looks like you have leaks. Regarding DDD principles your domain can't be exposed outside.

I guess, you should create some DTO model which will be able to expose only necessary data from User aggregate.

Furthermore, I also suggest to implement CQRS pattern here in order to distinguish between reads and writes...

Comment: Brother! Thanks for the answer.

I'm actually looking to start building my applications using **Clean Architecture** (I work with Node.js + TypeScript).
But, I found that this architecture needs **DDD** "modeling". So I'm going to have to start from the beginning.

At this point, I went back to MVC. I want to create something with **MVC + MVP** and, little by little insert the DDD concepts and then, architect the layers with Clean Architecture.

I think it's a good plan. :)

And of course, add **CQRS**.
I heard people saying that CQRS is not interesting in the whole project. Confirm?